# Accused of using company phone whereas a personal iPad was used

Tags: iphone, ipad, icloud, facetime

My boss is going to sack me tomorrow, because he says I used my company phone whilst driving the company van. I definitely didn't use my phone.  Sometimes I might audio [FaceTime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FaceTime) my girlfriend on my iPad (which has a different SIM card and is not a company iPad.). And she may phone me back but even though it rings on my phone it also rings on my iPad. How does this happen?

Comment: You need to speak to your union rep or a lawyer 0 just using a phone seems unlikely to be the whole issue

Answer (score 6):

Facetime will ring on any device you have registered your email address for the Facetime.app on that device.

There is an explanation [here on imore.com](http://www.imore.com/how-register-additional-email-address-facetime) which goes into some  details on how it works and how to register, enable and disable an email address on a device.

> **How to enable or disable phone numbers and email address for FaceTime**
>
> If you don't want your iPad or iPod touch to receive FaceTime calls
> sent to your iPhone phone number, or don't want your work iPhone or
> Mac to receive FaceTime calls sent to your personal email address, you
> can easily disable -- or enable -- them on a per-device, and
> per-address/number basis.
>
> 1, Launch the Settings app from the Home screen of your iPhone, iPad, or
> iPod touch.
>
> 2,Tap FaceTime.
>
> 3,Tap on the checkmark to the left of any
> number or address you want to turn off (prevent from calling FaceTime
> on that device).
>
> To enable or re-enable numbers or addresses, simply
> reverse the process and tap the empty space to the left to number or
> address to add a checkmark.

---

If you always carry both devices then there is no need to set up personal accounts on company equipment.

If the boss's entire case is based on a mobile call during a driving period (rather weak, you could have been parked / stopped etc.) then the whole situation is probably for another reason and this is just an excuse that will pass the labour board.